# Accesing data in JS after API request?

Tags: javascript, json

Trying to use the google fonts API to learn interacting with APIs etc. Whenever I try to access the data after parsing using dot notation it doesn't work, for example trying:

```
console.log(fonts);
```

or

```
console.log(fonts.family);
```

or

```
console.log(font.items[1].family);
```

Doesn't work, with all of these resulting in an array for either fonts or items not being declared. However, the .length of .items is output just fine, so I'm wondering if I have a fundamental misunderstanding with how to access this information?

Code:

```
var fontRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
fontRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (fontRequest.readyState === 4 && fontRequest.status === 200) {
        var fonts = JSON.parse(fontRequest.responseText);
        var family = fonts.items.family;
        var statusHTML = '<ul class="fonts">';
        for (var i = 0; i < fonts.items.length; i += 1) {
            statusHTML += '<li>' + i + ' ' + family + '</li>';
            document.getElementById('googleFonts').innerHTML = statusHTML;
        }
    }

};
fontRequest.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=?????');
fontRequest.send();
```

(Key has been hidden)

[image: Example of JSON recieved from request.]

Example of JSON recieved from request.

Could anyone tell me how, for example, to print out items.family inside of the loop?

plnkr here: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/mabE27maz64bQwM6G1JD?p=preview

Comment: could you setup a plunkr?

Comment: Try `console.log(font.items[0].family);`. Arrays are zero indexed.

Comment: plunkr has been added, can be found above! 
I'm not sure why I was trying [1], but the arrays length is over 700 items so don't think that has an effect, thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your result displayed in image, you should call

```
var family = items[0].family;
```

output will be  `ABeeZee`

**Edit**

Update your javascript function with following

```
var fontRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
fontRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (fontRequest.readyState === 4 && fontRequest.status === 200) {
        var fonts = JSON.parse(fontRequest.responseText);
        //var family = fonts.items[0].family;
        var statusHTML = '<ul class="fonts">';
        for (var i = 0; i < fonts.items.length; i += 1) {
            statusHTML += '<li>' + i + ' ' + fonts.items[i].family + '</li>';
            document.getElementById('googleFonts').innerHTML = statusHTML;
        }
    }
};
fontRequest.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyAyORnIjrvRi3StxS2gVuvIUBYPY7MZXiE');
fontRequest.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your statusHTML assignment as -
`statusHTML += '<li>' + i + ' ' + fonts.items[i].family + '</li>';`